# Can a bipartite graph not contain a Hamiltonian cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, bipartite-graphs

Statement: any bipartite graph contains a Hamiltonian  cycle.

My answer: No. A bipartite graph which have an odd number of vertices cannot contain a Hamiltonian cycle, since each simple cycle in a bipartite graph has an even number of edges and, therefore, contains an even number of vertices.

Comment: What is your question then? Do you want to check your answer?

Comment: Just draw a simple counterexample - two vertices suffice. Also, a bipartite graph need not even be connected